# componentWillReceiveProps() is triggered but it's not getting the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the component I have, I am using componentWillReceiveProps() to set multiple states in my component asynchronously. The parent component is sending the new props to this child. My expectation is that whenever the child gets the new props,  componentWillReceiveProps() is triggered and it receives the props and sets the states accordingly. The thing is it sometimes work properly and sometimes it doesn't! As you can see in the code I added an if condition, so that whenever `this.props.community` gets value it goes trough the statements in the if block.  But sometimes it doesn't and `this.props.community` remains `undefined`! Can someone explain me what is going on and how to fix it?

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.componentWillReceiveProps(this.props);
},

componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    if(this.props.community && this.state.record){
        if(...){
             this.setState({....});
    } else {
        console.log("this.props.community = ", this.props.community) // undefined
        console.log("this.state.record = ", this.state.record) 
    }
},
```

Comment: I'm not sure you should be calling `this.componentWillReceiveProps()` from `componentWillMount`, as per the docs `componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component receives new props` please see docs - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops :-)

React calls `componentWillReceiveProps()` as part of its lifecycle, like `componentDidMount...` etc - let React handle the passing of the `props (or) nextProps` argument passed to `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: @FrancisLeigh is absolutely right. This will never work, because ReactJS triggers the componentWillReceiveProps itself.

Why do you want to do this? Maybe you should create a seperate method for your case

Comment: you cant 'send' props to component will receive props,its a lifecycle method.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps ` will only called when you are re-rendering the component by react itself. Programmatically you can not called it

Comment: @FrancisLeigh, @all, I removed `componentDidMount()`, but the same thing still happens.

Comment: @birish are you needing a constructor in your component?

Answer (score 1):

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.community !== this.props.community) {
    this.setState({community: nextProps.community})
  }
}
```

The argument for componentWillReceiveProps is the new incoming props. this.props.community is the current props and is 'old'. Whatever async you have probably hasn't returned with 'community' yet.